# SmartGWT throws JavaScriptException: (null): null

Tags: smartgwt

When using GWT 2.0.x and SmartGWT 2.2
Code as simple as:

```
public class SmartGwtTest implements EntryPoint {    
    public void onModuleLoad() {  
        IButton button = new IButton("say hello");
    }
}
```

will generate the exception.

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null):
```

This only happens in hosted (devmode)

```
ant hosted
```

I also suspect that maybe the GWT Development Plugin might have something to do with it.

Have you found a similar problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer but a workaround was to use compile the app.
And use it that way.

```
ant build
```

Although compilation takes a long time because it generates several permutations of the code. ie different versions for different browser to make compilation faster you can set your target browser while testing.

to do that in your ModuleName.gwt.xml file add the following line:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko"/>
<!-- to test with firefox -->
```

That will make compilation faster.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was getting this in Firefox in hosted mode and it turned out that a widget was set to have width100 but there was not enough room on the screen to render the widget (my browser was not maximized).

I think this resulted in a negative width being set and this ambiguous Javascript exception was thrown as a result. Maximizing the browser alleviated the issue, you might want to try setting a width to begin with and using resize handlers to render your widget properly.